# Meteor 1.3 - lazy loading or evaluation of files

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I am very excited with ES2015 `modules` in Meteor 1.3. We have written an app with medium complexity with Meteor 1.2. As we have very large number of templates and files, it is taking a bit of time to download the content on client side. so I am interested in the lazy loading feature using `import`. From the [meteor night talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7d0xTR-eYh0), they say that the Blaze templates are still global and cannot be imported (or lazy loaded), I have tried [using `React` inside `Blaze`](http://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-with-blaze).

- Added `react-template-helper` package using `meteor add react-template-helper`
- Create `imports` folder and added `testComponent.jsx` file which exports 'TestComponent'

  ```
  //testComponent.jsx
  import React from 'react';

  export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <h1>TestComponent</h1>
              <div>This is from Test Component</div>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
  ```
- After in the Blaze template outside `imports` folder,

  ```
  <!-- homeReact template html-->
  <template name="homeReact">
      <div>
          {{> React component=TestComponent}}
      </div>
  </template>
  ```
- In the template's js file which is also outside of imports folder

  ```
  // homeReact template js
  import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

  import TestComponent from '/imports/testComponent.jsx`;

  Template.homeReact.helpers({
    TestComponent() {
      return TestComponent;
    }
  });
  ```

This worked but the `imports/testComponent.jsx` is downloaded on the client (checked using chrome dev tools - sources tab), even if the current route doesn't require `homeReact` template.

Then I have used `require` instead of `import` like this,

```
    // homeReact template js
    import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

    Template.homeReact.onCreated(function () {
        this.TestComponent = require('/imports/testComponent.jsx').TestComponent;
    });

    Template.homeReact.helpers({
      TestComponent() {
        return Template.instance().TestComponent;
      }
    });
```

This code also downloads the `imports/testComponent.jsx` file but in addition I also got an error

> In template "homeReact", call to `{{> React ... }}` missing `component` argument.

So, my question is, is it possible to lazy load (download) files only when required?